# How to apply eulers method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do you apply Euler's method to x'=Ax. I always thought with Euler's method you needed an initial condition? Also the constant A confuses me

Comment: What is the context? Is $A$ a matrix, $x$ a vector? Are you looking for numerical solutions? Or solutions using the matrix exponential?

Comment: Im looking for numerical solutions it doesnt say what x or A is but im guessing its not a vector

Comment: So what is the problem in iterating $\frac{x_{k+1}-x_k}{h}=Ax_k\iff x_{k+1}=x_k+hAx_k$? Apart from the fact that indeed you will need some $x_0$. Please give a more complete description of the task and what you know about the Euler method.